# When I load the project it is saying that the form files aren't in a specific directory

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I'm trying to modify an  c# windows form project. In Visual studio 2013 when I load the project it is saying that the form files aren't in a specific directory instead of looking in the directory where the project is.

I've looked all over the application for where I could set that path, but no luck.
I can't find any project file (vbp.) like is it in visual basic 6.

How do you set the path for the project files in Visual studio 2013?